# How can I allow cancellation of running work with the IScheduler.SchedulePeriodic method of Rx in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, system.reactive

I want to run some work periodically using the IScheduler.SchedulePeriodic method in Rx. I want to be able to cancel the work not just between executions but also (cooperatively) while the work is running by allowing the work to accept a `CancellationToken` that is canceled when the IDisposable returned from SchedulePeriodic is disposed.

Disposal of the IDisposable should not block until the work is canceled, just provide the opportunity for the work to cancel itself at the next opportunity.

How can I do this using Rx in .NET 4.0?

It looks like the [cooperative cancellation support added in Rx 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx) (see the section "Making schedulers easier to use with 'await'") could help with this but it's not available in .NET 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the extension method I came up with:

```
public static IDisposable SchedulePeriodic(
    this IScheduler scheduler,
    TimeSpan interval,
    Action<CancellationToken> work) {

    if (scheduler == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("scheduler");
    }
    if (work == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("work");
    }

    var cancellationDisposable = new CancellationDisposable();

    var subscription = scheduler.SchedulePeriodic(
        interval,
        () => {
            try {
                work(cancellationDisposable.Token);
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                if (e.CancellationToken != cancellationDisposable.Token) {
                    // Something other than the token we passed in threw this exception
                    throw;
                }
            }
        });

    return new CompositeDisposable(cancellationDisposable, subscription);
}
```